# PHP timezone conversion

Tags: php, timezone

I have a `DateTime Object` `$dt`

`var_dump($dt)` produces:

```
object(DateTime)[230]
  public 'date' => string '2016-02-09 10:00:30.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

I am trying to convert this to PST:

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$dt->setTimezone($tz);
```

another `var_dump($dt)` produces:

```
object(DateTime)[230]
  public 'date' => string '2016-02-09 02:00:30.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Los_Angeles' (length=19)
```

It appears that the converted time is 8hrs earlier. I was under the assumption that PST is actually 7hrs earlier.

Is this converting correctly and my assumption is wrong or vice versa?

Comment: Depends on daylight savings - http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst

Comment: Ahh, makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pacific Time Zone is UTC-8
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone